# Error building AAR from existing React Native Project

Tags: android, react-native, aar

I tried to build an AAR from my existing React Native Project by following the guide from the Android Native documentations (https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library)

But I got the following error when I tried to sync the gradle
[image]

I've read the solutions from https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera/issues/1454 about the CMakeLists and fbjni, but I still get the error.

Is there any solution to this?
Or maybe there's another way to build **AAR** or even **Maven Repository** from existing React Native Project?

Comment: @Grateful I still don't find any solution and moving to Android Native instead using Kotlin